# Changing reference values in a List

Tags: c#, reference

I am passing an object of type Entry from a list of Entry into a helper function, which takes in a reference to the Entry object:

```
for(int i = 0; i < entries.Count; i ++)
{
     Entry singleEntry = entries[i];
     bool success = Helper(ref singleEntry);
}
```

In the helper function, a new Entry object is created and I want entries[i] to reference the new object instead of the old one, but only singleEntry is actually changed. I tried to do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < entries.Count; i ++)
{     
     bool success = Helper(ref entries[i]);
}
```

But I got an error: "A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter".

I ended up changing entries[i] by adding this line:

```
for(int i = 0; i < entries.Count; i ++)
{
     Entry singleEntry = entries[i];
     bool success = Helper(ref singleEntry);

     entries[i] = singleEntry;
}
```

Is there a more elegant solution to changing the references in a List?

Comment: Your solution (in the third code example) is correct, keep it like that.

Comment: Striving for elegance is good, but your code is doing strange things while using vaguely named methods (`Helper`??), and I would be more worried about the readability/maintainability of my code than its elegance.

Comment: I definitely agree that it should be readable first. My example is just a modified, much simpler version of the actual code for asking purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your below portion of code is the best and most commonly accepted way to achieve what you are wanting.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < entries.Count; i ++)
 {
     Entry singleEntry = entries[i];
     bool success = Helper(ref singleEntry);
     entries[i] = singleEntry;
 }
```

You also could use the unsafe part of c#(pointers) but that would be very nasty, frowned upon heavily, and might I mention unsafe.

Comment: The OP says their helper method creates a new `Entry`, not that it updates a field/property.  So change that to have `element = new Entry();` before you change `s` and you'll see this does not work.

Comment: @juharr Thanks for letting me know. I edited my answer accordingly.